# Is it possible to use AAD delegated permissions without physical user login?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I would like an AAD app to act on behalf of a user, without requiring the user to login to authenticate himself.  E.g., I would like an app to be able to send an email from a user's account on the user's behalf programmatically using Graph API, but based on an event, and without user sign in each time to authenticate.  Is this something that is possible using AAD delegated permissions?

I cannot use the client credentials flow using application permissions, because my admin will not grant access to my app, so I am looking for a viable workaround.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You will need the user to consent your app using his/her e-mail address. Or an admin consenting the app to use everyones e-mail address. No other way.

Check out [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-api-authentication) which describes dealing with long term access to APIs without presence of the user. And [this here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-scopes), describing the `offline_access` scope.

But, without someone letting you use their e-mail, you cannot use it. Period.

Comment: Thanks.  To clarify, the user wants me to use his email, the problem is only that he would need to log in to approve each time, and I have an event-based trigger that should send the email, not a user-driven trigger.  I will look into Resource Manager authentication, hadn't seen anything about that previously.

Comment: not each time. Read the provided docs. Your server side code only needs one time interactive login. Then it can work until the user changes his/her password or his refresh token is explicitly expired. Resource manager authentication is just an example.